# When building custom panels for Flash CS4 IDE, is there a way to attach callbacks to workspace events?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, jsfl

Is there a way for a custom panel for Flash CS4 to register for IDE events?

I've built a custom panel for the CS4 IDE, and now I'd like to get a callback anytime the current selection on the stage changes.  Is this possible?

My backup plan is to have my panel poll the IDE for the selected object several times a second, but this is weak, and won't extend to other kinds of events like deleting objects from the stage or saving the file.

Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CS4, yes there are a few events.

There is no *selectionChangedEvent* unforunately, 
buy maybe you can work out something using *frameChanged* or *documentChanged*. 
DocumentChanged might be more often than you need. Try on frameChanged.
More events are listener in the [fl.addEventListener() reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_ExtendingFlash/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7fb6.html).

Also, [here](http://summitprojectsflashblog.wordpress.com/2009/03/03/jsfl-event-listeners-and-window-swf-panels/) is a handy post on fl events and swfPanel.

Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks, George!  That was exactly what I've been looking for.